# Need to configure network card manually after each reboot

Tags: virtual-machine, init-script, suse, networkcard

I am using SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64) as VM Ware virtual machine (that was cloned). Not sure why but network card cannot be configured via yast2. If I go to edit and hit enter Yast will go back to "Control Center". Also in yast2 I can see that the card is "not connected". No idea what it means though.

But if I go command line and issue these two commands the network is up and running.

```
ifconfig eth1 10.0.0.xxx netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 10.0.0.255
route add default gw 10.0.0.1 eth1
```

From /var/log/messages

```
Jun 18 14:20:19 Edumate kernel: [  221.986998] e1000: eth1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
Jun 18 14:20:19 Edumate kernel: [  221.988366] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
Jun 18 14:20:19 Edumate kernel: [  221.988482] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth1: link becomes ready
Jun 18 14:20:29 Edumate kernel: [  232.399704] eth1: no IPv6 routers present
```

- Q1: Would anybody know how to fix the network configuration or
- Q2: What files I update with above two commands so I can have network up and running after each reboot?

## EDITs

- removing `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` and rebooting didn't help
- content of /etc/sysconfig/network

Edu:/var/lib/edu/bdrs # cd /etc/sysconfig/network

Edu:/etc/sysconfig/network # ll

```
total 108
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 13192 Jun  5 16:30 config
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 13181 Jun  5 15:42 config.backup.by.convert_to_netconfig
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7482 Jun 18 14:10 dhcp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7686 Jun  5 15:42 dhcp.backup.by.convert_to_netconfig
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jun  5 15:42 if-down.d
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jun  5 15:42 if-up.d
-rw------- 1 root root   172 Jan 31 23:45 ifcfg-lo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 29333 Jan 31 23:45 ifcfg.template
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   239 Jan 31 23:45 ifroute-lo
drwx------ 2 root root  4096 May  6  2010 providers
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    22 Jun 18 14:07 routes
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Jun 18 14:07 routes.YaST2save
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jun  5 15:42 scripts
```

Comment: What's in your `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: `/etc/network` directory doesn't exist on my system

Comment: Ok, what's in your `/etc/sysconfig/network` then?

Comment: @ott: please see my Edits

Comment: @tripleee `/etc/network/interfaces` is on Debian and derivatives. On SuSE and Red Hat, these settings are in `/etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On SuSE, you can [configure the network manually](http://www.novell.com/documentation/suse91/suselinux-adminguide/html/ch14s03.html) via files in [`/etc/sysconfig/network`](http://linux.frank4dd.com/en/man8/ifup.htm). Create a file called `/etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-eth1` [containing](https://www.linode.com/wiki/index.php/Configure_Static_IPs#OpenSUSE)

```
STARTMODE=onboot
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=10.0.0.xxx
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
BROADCAST=10.0.0.255
```

The default route needs to be set in [`/etc/sysconfig/network/routes`](http://www.novell.com/documentation/suse91/suselinux-adminguide/html/ch14s05.html).

```
default 10.0.0.1 - eth1
```

Comment: By doing so I am able to edit the network card in yast but after reboot the card is not up.

Comment: In yast I can see "activate device" at boot time setting to be on.

Comment: @Radek Sorry, I'd mixed up RH and SuSE. Try my edit.

Comment: You're a genius. I can reboot and network is up then. Thank you so much.

Comment: One more thing. Could you by any chance explain what happened? Configuration got lost when cloning virtual machine?