# SUSE Linux 15 - ifcfg-eth0 deleted after reboot

Tags: networking, configuration, ip, suse, yast

I have a Virtual Machine with a clean installation of SUSE Linux For SAP Applications 15. I configured the network with YaST Network (IP address assigned, file `/etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-eth0` automatically created, everything looked good). When OS is rebooted, file ifcfg-eth0 is missing and I have to configure the network again.

Does anybody know why file ifcfg-eth0 is deleted after reboot?
Does OS do it on purpose? Do I need SUSE License?

Comment: This has nothing to do with a subscription (they don't sell licences). Did that just happen once or everytime you change the setting? Do you see anything like a read-only filesystem? Try to remove the config and then reboot without changing it. And then after reboot first check if there's anything suspicious in /etc/sysconfig/network. If not, reconfigure the network again with yast and test a reboot.

Comment: Every time. Created file ifroute-eth0, DNS IP address in /etc/resolv.conf, installed files and programs remained. I Have only one mountpoint "/".

Comment: This [topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79798/need-to-configure-network-card-manually-after-each-reboot?rq=1) looks extremely similar because my VM is also on VM ware and was moved to another HW. But OS was installed after moving to another HW.

Comment: in SLES 15 you don't update the file /etc/resolv.conf anymore, you do it in /etc/sysconfig/network/config and after that you run `netconfig -f update`. Please update your question with the information that your VM moved to a different hardware.